# react-native mp4 upload is sending [object Object]

Tags: react-native, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file from the users phone to the server. However, instead of sending the file, it keeps just sending this over the network.

```
file: [object Object]
```

Here is the code I'm using

```
const foo = 'file:///data/user/0/my_app/cache/Camera/58ce5eed-edd5-4bf5-9a08-ae40a13cbcd1.mp4'
const upload = () => {
  const data = new FormData()
  data.append('file', {
    uri: foo,
    type: 'video/mp4',
    name: '58ce5eed-edd5-4bf5-9a08-ae40a13cbcd1.mp4'
  });

  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/video-upload/', {
    method: 'post',
    body: data
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log('SUCCESS', res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('ERROR: ', err)
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes. Sorry the issue was react-native debugger on android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works. The issue was react-native debugger on android.